# Repeated-measures regression in single subject design

Tags: lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I'm grateful for advice on which R analysis to choose for the following study:

I measured stress in one subject on 27 days in the night and in the morning.

Now I want to predict stress in the night via stress in the morning. All data stem from the same subject. There are 27 timepoints in total.

How do I account for the repeated measures in this?

A normal lm doesn't work since it's repeated. When i use lme4, R gives a warning: If i cluster within ID (always the same participant) the warning is: I have to have more than 1 observation. If I cluster within video (27 videos) R warns that the number of clusters has to be smaller than the number of observations.

I have thought about uSEM, lme4, gee or dynamic linear regression.

Do you have any ideas how I model this? I always want to predict the stress in the night by the stress the former day.

Any advice is very welcome and thank you so much for reading this far.

> head(data)

> dailystress nightstress dailystress.l1 Video
>                             
> 1         0.333           0.166               0.183      1
> 2         1               0.142               0.166      2
> 3         0               0.0741              0.142      3
> 4        NA               0.138               0.0741     4
> 5         1               0.0567              0.138      5
> 6         0.667           0.102               0.0567     6

str(data) is

> dailystress: num [1:26] 0.333 1 0 NA 1
> ..- attr("format.spss")= chr "F8.2"
> ..- attr("display_width")= int 14
> nightstress: num [1:26] 0.1658 0.1424 0.0741 0.138 0.0567
> ..- attr("format.spss")= chr "F20.8"
> ..- attr("display_width")= int 22
> dailystress.l1: num [1:26] 0.1834 0.1658 0.1424 0.0741 0.138
> ..- attr("format.spss")= chr "F20.8"
> ..- attr("display_width")= int 25
> Video: num [1:26] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
> ..- attr(*, "format.spss")= chr "F8.0"

Answer (score 0):

Consider a model like the following for your data

stress$_{td} \sim N(\mu_t+\pi_d, ~\sigma^2),~\pi_d \sim N(0,~\tau^2)$,

where $t$ codes the time (morning, afternoon) and $d$ indexes the 27 days. If Gaussianity is a reasonable assumption, you can analyze the data with the above model formulation using `lme4` or `nlme`:

```
m1 <- lmer(stress ~ time+(1|day), data=...)
summary(m1)

m2 <- lme(stress ~ time, random=~1|day, data=...)
summary(m2)
```

---

**P.S.**

The previous recommendation was based on the assumption that the primary focus is on comparing `dailystress` and `nightstress`, and this additional information has been incorporated following the OP's update.

Lacking direct access to the dataset, providing a specific recommendation is challenging. Instead, I offer a more general approach:

1. Theoretical Hypothesis: Clearly formulate your theoretical hypothesis regarding the relationship between `dailystress` and `nightstress`. Define the expected patterns or trends.
2. Data Visualization: Plot the data to gain insights. Visualization can reveal patterns, trends, or anomalies that align with or challenge your theoretical hypothesis. Tools like scatter plots, or time-series plots can be insightful.
3. Modeling: Consider employing an autoregressive model or its derivatives. In R, the `ar` function could be a good starting point. Such models can capture temporal dependencies in the data, which might be crucial when studying stress patterns over time.

This approach encourages a structured exploration of the data, ensuring that your analysis is guided by your theoretical expectations. Visualization aids in uncovering nuances, and an autoregressive model provides a statistical framework for capturing temporal dependencies, a common consideration in stress-related studies.

Comment: Thank you so much @bluepole, that was beyond helpful. If I may ask: If I cluster for days, like in the formula, R gives me the error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: day). I will try to split up daypoints so there are three measurements a day instead of using mean and having only one pair of observation each day. Then I can still cluster for 27 days but the levels are < number of observations. Does that make sense to you? Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Would you mind sharing  in your original post the output of `str()` and `head()` for your data frame?

Comment: For sure, again thank you so much for asking. I put it in the original post. Video contains 27 videos from the same person. Video is the same variable as day in the model (27 days = 27 videos). Using your model : m1 <- lmer(nightstress ~ dailystress+(1|Video), data=data) I get this error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: Video). If anything is unclear, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Your reply suggests that you may be interested in examining the relationship or dependence between `nightstress` and `dailystress`. Could you clarify if this is indeed the aspect of interest, or if you are focusing on the difference between the two?

Comment: Exactly, I want to predict dailystress by nightstress. So I would like to examine this relationship, but dailystress and nightstress is repeatedly measured on the 27 days.

Comment: I added some recommendation based on your updated information.